# spresense Serial2 制御

Tags: spresense

現在使用しているバージョンは1.3.1です。
・Arduino IDE(VSCode)を使用。

ハードウェアドキュメントを参照しますと、拡張ボード側のUARTは調歩同期式で、メインボードと拡張ボードを組み合わせた場合は、出荷時には自動的に拡張ボードのUARTが使用できる設定となっています。
拡張ボード側のUARTが有効な場合、メインボードのUARTをGPIOとして設定した場合には、D27, D28のみ使用可能です。と記載されています。
UARTの設定等は特に操作していませんので、出荷状態の拡張ボードのUARTが使用できる設定になっていると思います。

D27,D28を入力に設定してプルアップしているのですが、この状態ですとSerial2から何も送信されません。フロー制御が無効になっていないような感じなのですが、D27,D28を使用するには、pinModeの他に何か特別な設定等必要なのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。

お問い合わせいただきましたUART2使用時のピンのモードですが、
ホームページ上のハードウェアドキュメントに誤りがございました。
現在は訂正が済んでおりますので、下記の回答と併せて以下のページをご参照ください。
[https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/hw_docs_ja.html#_uartの使用方法](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/hw_docs_ja.html#_uart%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95)

UART2をシリアルポートとして使用する場合には、UART2_TX, UART2_RX, UART2_RTS, UART2_CTS
の４ピンはまとめてフロー制御付きのシリアルポート動作となりますので、
UART2_RTS, UART2_CTSの2ピンを独立してGPIOとして使用することはできません。

ご迷惑をお掛けしてしまい申し訳ございません。

今後ともSPRESENSEをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

SPRESENSEサポートチーム

Answer (score 1):

UARTは、Universal Asynchronous Receiver/Transmitterの略で、受信機(Receiver)と送信機(Transmitter)両方の機能を持っています。

そのため、UARTから出ている２本のピンの一方は入力（データ受信用）、もう一方は出力（データ送信用）です。

「D27,D28を入力に設定してプルアップ」ということは、データ送信用のピンも入力に設定されている訳です。
送信用のピンからデータが出てこないのは、そのピンの設定が入力になっているからではないでしょうか？

Comment: SPRESENSEでは通常のデジタル端子をソフトウェアシリアルライブラリを使用することでシリアル端子としても使用可能です。
今回はそれではなく、元々割り当てられているD0(RX)、D1(TX)をシリアル端子として使用しています。
ドキュメントによるとこのD0,D1はメイン基板、拡張基板どちらにも端子が出ていますが、メイン基板の場合はフロー制御付き。拡張基板の場合は調歩同期のUARTとして使用できます。
どちらも同じポートなので、同時には使用できません。
今回は拡張基板での使用を想定していますので、調歩同期のUARTとなります。
現在入力に設定してあるD27(CTS),D28(RTS)はフロー制御の場合に使用するか通常のGPIO端子のどちらかで使用できます。
・メインボードと拡張ボードを組み合わせた場合は、出荷時には自動的に拡張ボードのUARTが使用できる設定となっています。
・拡張ボード側のUARTが有効な場合、メインボードのUARTをGPIOとして設定した場合には、D27, D28のみ使用可能です。
という記載もあります。
D27,28は今回UARTでは使用しませんので、通常のGPIO端子として使用できるはずです。
ということは、自動的に拡張ボードのUARTが有効になるのでD27,D28は特に設定しなくてもGPIOに割り当てられるはず。

Comment: しかし、D27をプルアップしてHIGHにしているとUARTが送信されない。ということはCTSの機能が割り当てられている？と考えられます。
SPRESENSE SDKでの開発をしている場合は、ピンの機能設定の仕方がガイドに記載されていましたが、今回はArduino IDEでの開発をしています。
Arudinoの場合、ピン機能設定は特にガイドに載っていませんでした。そもそもArduinoの場合そういった機能変更の設定ができないのか。あるいは設定方法があるならばご教授願います。

Comment: RTSとCTSは、シリアル通信のフロー制御用の信号線です。

Comment: spresenseと通信相手とは、どのような接続（配線）がされているのですか？　「Serial2から何も送信されません」というのは、どのピンの信号をオシロスコープなどで観測したことを根拠にしているのですか？　通信相手のシリアル通信信号の仕様(電圧)は、どうなっていますか？

Answer (score 0):

Arduino IDEでSerial2(UART2)の動作を確認してみました。
結論から言うとSerial2はフロー制御付きのシリアルポート動作となります。

CTSに外部からHIGH(1.8V)を入力した状態でSerial2.writeとするとデータは送信されません。
CTSをHIGH→LOWと切り替えると送信バッファに溜まっていたデータが一度に送信されます。
また受信データをSerial2.readせずにいると受信バッファがいっぱいになったタイミングでRTSがHIGH(1.8V)になります。
Serial2.readで受信データをいくらか引き抜くとRTSはHIGH→LOWに変化しました。